# Sorting a NSArray with NSDictionary inside it

Tags: ios, objective-c, sorting, nsarray, nsdictionary

I need to sort my array from *Monday to Friday* sequentially. I did that part here

```
NSArray *userDays = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"Monday", @"Tuesday", @"Wednesday",@"Thursday",@"Friday",nil];
[sortArray addObject:model.title];
NSArray *sortedUserDays = [userDays filteredArrayUsingPredicate:[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF in (%@)", sortArray]];
```

So, *sortArray* has 5 objects which is Monday, Tuesday, Wednesday, Thursday and Friday. The problem is when I sort the array that needs to be sorted, let's say *tempArray*. I just created the sortArray for testing purposes of my sorting.

*tempArray* has NSDictionary inside it. And the days (monday,tuesday,etc...) are in the key *title*.

Now in this line

```
NSArray *sortedUserDays = [userDays filteredArrayUsingPredicate:[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF in (%@)", sortArray]];
```

I need to change *sortArray* by something like *tempArray.model.title*. How can I do that in order to sort the nested NSArray?

Example data:

```
tempArray[0]
{ title : "Friday", identity: "someUniqueIdentity", url: "httpwww.123" }

tempArray[1]
{ title: "Wednesday", identity: "someUniqueIdentity2", url :"httpwww.1233" }

tempArray[2]
{ title: "Monday", identity: "someUniqueIdentity3", url: "httpwww.1233" }


tempArray[3]
{ title: "Thursday", identity: "someUniqueIdentity3", url :"httpwww.1233" }


tempArray[4]
{ title: "Tuesday", identity: "someUniqueIdentity3", url: "httpwww.1233" }
```

Expected output:

```
tempArray[0]
{ title: "Monday", identity: "someUniqueIdentity3", url: "httpwww.1233" }

tempArray[1]
{ title: "Tuesday", identity: "someUniqueIdentity3", url :"httpwww.1233" }

tempArray[2]
{ title: "Wednesday", identity: "someUniqueIdentity2", url :"httpwww.1233" }

tempArray[3]
{ title: "Thursday", identity: "someUniqueIdentity3", url :"httpwww.1233" }

tempArray[4]
{ title: "Friday", identity: "someUniqueIdentity", url: "httpwww.123" }
```

Comment: can i know shortly what you want to do?

Comment: What you are doing is filter not sort, first you need to cleat about it.

Comment: Sort my nested NSArray with the format Monday, Tuesday, Wednesday, Thursday and Friday

Comment: @Supermannoying Your nested array is type of Array of Dictionary and each dictionary contains key title and its value is like `userDays` element. Right?

Comment: @NiravD Yup! And I need to filter it. Sorry I just knew filtering just now. So, I want my Array of Dictionary to be filtered in the userDays format

Comment: @Supermannoying Means you want filter array that have days like your days array?

Comment: @NiravD Exactly, without losing other keys of my array

Comment: Please explain what you want really. You talk about sorting and filtering, but end up mixing all. Could you give a small example, with a input data and wanted result?

Comment: @Supermannoying Check this answer of my http://stackoverflow.com/a/40802798/6433023 here  instead of `idObjectToSearch` key you need to write you `title` key.

Comment: @Supermannoying First you need to confirm you want sort or filter.

Comment: @NiravD I can't differentiate the two. But see my sample data and the expected data. What function would match?

Comment: @Supermannoying Are you having repeated data in tempArray, means multiple `Monday` or `Tuesday` etc?

Comment: `NSArray *sortedArray = [arrayOfDicts sortedArrayUsingComparator:^(NSDictionary* dict1, NSDictionary* dict2){NSString *title1 = dict1[@"title"]; NSString *title2 = dict2[@"title"]; return [@([userDays indexOfObject:title1]) compare:@([userDays indexOfObject:title2]);}];`

Comment: @NiravD Nope, all of the data in tempArray is unique

Comment: @Supermannoying You are looking for this one http://stackoverflow.com/a/18089499/6433023

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure that I understand what you are looking for, but could it be something like this?

```
NSArray *tempArray = @[
        @{ @"title": @"Friday", @"identity" : @"someUniqueIdentity", @"url" : @"httpwww.123"},
        @{ @"title" : @"Wednesday", @"identity" :  @"someUniqueIdentity2", @"url" :  @"httpwww.1233" },
        @{ @"title" : @"Monday", @"identity" :  @"someUniqueIdentity3", @"url" :  @"httpwww.1233" },
        @{ @"title" : @"Thursday", @"identity" :  @"someUniqueIdentity3", @"url" :  @"httpwww.1233" },
        @{ @"title" : @"Tuesday", @"identity" :  @"someUniqueIdentity3", @"url" :  @"httpwww.1233" }
];

NSArray *weekdays = @[@"Monday", @"Tuesday", @"Wednesday", @"Thursday", @"Friday"];

NSSortDescriptor *descriptor = [NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"title" ascending:YES comparator:^NSComparisonResult(NSString *day1, NSString *day2) {
    NSUInteger index1 = [weekdays indexOfObject:day1];
    NSUInteger index2 = [weekdays indexOfObject:day2];
    return (NSComparisonResult) (index1 >= index2);
}];

NSArray *result = [tempArray sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:@[descriptor]];
```

Comment: Yup. I tried this `NSArray *filteredUser = [user filteredArrayUsingPredicate:[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF in (%@)", [tempArray valueForKey:@"title"]]];` but the filteredUser now is a NSArray with just 5 objects, monday to friday. The other keys are gone

Comment: @Supermannoying Edited my answer. You should probably make the code a little more robust, though..